# ORMLite Foreign field class does not have id field

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I've seen the same exact errors on other questions about this problem. As you can see, it does not seem like I have anything wrong! Unless my eyes have been deceiving me. Any help?

Here are my two models:

```
public class Outer {

    @DatabaseField(id = true, canBeNull = false, columnName = "id")
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField
    private long parentOuterId;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    private ForeignCollection<Item> items;
    //getters and setters
}


public class Item {

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, columnName = "id")
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
    private Outer out;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to add `id = true` or `generatedId = true` to the `@DatabaseField` annotation:

```
@DatabaseField(id = true, canBeNull = false, columnName = "id")
private int id;
```